# How to use ssh tail command and write to local file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I'm trying to write a script that reads logs from 3 linux machines and writes the logs (with some kind of prefix) in one file.

My problem is that I can access to the file in order to see it, but when I try to write it doesn't work.

Working code

```
expect -c "
spawn ssh user@x.x.x.x \" tail -f my_file\"
expect { 
   \"*assword\" {send \"PASS\r\";}
}
expect eof 
"
```

if I add

```
tail -f >> my_file.log
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: you do mean `tail -f filename` in both cases I hope.

Comment: @meuh - your are correct

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would highly recommend learning how to use SSH with keys so that you don't need a password.

Then, all you need to do is this:

```
ssh username@server 'tail -f filename' >> my_file.log
```

Comment: i know that i can create key between the machines, but for this case i can't. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: @Ofer: Use `expect` to set up keys, and then use my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your command

```
tail -f filename >> my_file.log
```

is being run on the remote. So my_file.log is on the remote. To get the output to a local file, move the `>> my_file.log` to the end of the expect script:

```
 expect -c "..." >> my_file.log
```